# WPF Rendering issues when used on Medium Colour monitor(16bit colour)

Tags: wpf

I'am testing a WPF application, and I have noticed a strange issue.

I am using duel monitors one is using the 32bit High colour, the other is using 16bit Medium colour. This is so that I can match the resolutions nicely.

If I open the application on my high colour screen I have no problems, but if I open it on my medium colour screen I get a terrible graphics lag, as soon as I move the mouse over the application. It makes it impossible to use the app on this screen.

Is this likely to be a problem with WPF or the Application? and is there any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to match the resolutions at any color depth.

Comment: @SLaks Possibly not if the monitors are driven by different cards and the other card only supports the desired resolution at a different colour depth.

Comment: @chibacity: What non-ancient card doesn't support 32bit color?

Comment: @SLaks I'm not saying the card does not support 32-bit colour at all. Some older cards only support their higher resolutions at a reduced colour depth, whilst supporting lower resolutions at 32-bit colour.

Comment: @Jambobond Is this software distributed to a large number of users where this could be a potential issue (at least in a number of cases)?

Comment: @chibacity Yes this software is distributed to a very large client base, some of which run ridiculously old hardware.
@SLaks Yes I agree that in theory you shouldn't mismatch colour depths, in general it will cause tearing etc between monitors. However This was not the question I asked, I asked if WPF had a problem with low colour depth displays. Using Duel monitors at different colour depths was how I discovered the issue not the cause. I get the same issues running the application on single monitor 16bit colour.

Answer (score 3):

[This an issue with the graphics pipeline; it has been described by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100208-00/?p=15023).

In short, don't do that.
Avoid monitors with differing color depths at all costs.

Comment: Not the question I asked see above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem... A colleague found out, that the problem is the Windows-Transparency. If you deactivate that on the 16bit screen, it works.